# OpenGL ES has a maximum speed limit?

Tags: multithreading, opengl-es, frame-rate

I implemented a loop with up to 100fps and can not spend more than 63fps.

What I believe is that the thread that runs the method of drawing opengl has a speed limit.
"(
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
)"

Comment: Wouldn't want OpenGL ES to get a traffic ticket, now would we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether or not your rendering context has vertical sync enabled.  Most LCD devices refresh at 60hz, and it may be waiting for the next refresh to call onDrawFrame().  That's one reason you'd be seeing that number.

The other possibility is that your draw is just taking long enough that it can't run any faster.

Comment: Drawn consumption is way too small, I'm not drawing anything big  just a dot on the screen.

must be what you said of the frequency of the screen, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the spec, for eglSwapInterval. It has to be implemented in your driver (I presume this is an Android device) to be able to see the effect. You can use it in any OpenGLES2 based application.

http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglSwapInterval.html

A gist showing the usage here:

https://gist.github.com/prabindh/8467984

Comment: Ok, but is possible change this configuration in opengl es?

Comment: @SamuelLiz Even if you could, there's really no point in rendering faster than the screen refresh rate.  Unless you're trying to benchmark something.

Comment: @SamuelLiz, yes it is an EGL API. For example, if you pass parameter n, the driver will wait for n Vsync refresh cycles before it updates the drawn buffer to screen. If 0, it will refresh as fast as you send the buffers.